# New Site Collection isn't secure (i.e. SSL) like our other

Tags: site-collection, iis, ssl, alternate-access-mapping

I created a web app (sharepoint2.xyz.com), then extended it (AAM) to sharepoint.xyz.com.  I also created a Site Collection called sharepoint2.xyz.com with our subsites under that (to mimic our 2007 install).  All above sites & subsites utilize SSL successfully (https://sharepoint2, etc and https://sharepoint, etc.  The problem is I've created a new Site Collection (sharepoint2.xyz.com/sites/NewSite) and it works using either the sharepoint2 or sharepoint URL, however, but not using the https URL. SSL does not work.  In IIS, we had previously defined both http and https for sharepoint2.xyz.com but only http for sharepoint.xyz.com.  In an attempt in resolving this issue, we added the binding for https to sharepoint.xyz.com in IIS but that causes sharepoint.xyz.com to be completely inaccessible.

Could someone please offer some advice?  Thanks!!

Comment: This is a little confusing. You said sites utilize ssl successfully then you say you added binding to sharepoint.xyz.com and it doesn't work. Can you detail each site and the AAM setup for each? Each AAM has to be setup in IIS bindings as well.

Comment: My apologies.  Our main Web App is sharepoint2.xyz.com.  Under that are site collections sharepoint2.xyz.com and our recently created sharepoint2.xyz.com/sites/NewSite.  Months ago, I created the AAM sharepoint.xyz.com which points to sharepoint2.xyz.com.  All works fine for those sites - SSL and non-SSL access.  Our new site (sharepoint2.xyz.com/sites/NewSite) does not work using SSL.  In IIS, I have two entries under Sites sharepoint2.xyz.com and sharepoint.xyz.com.  http & https is defined on sharepoint2 but only http on sharepoint.  If I add https binding to sharepoint, it no longer loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharepoint.xyz.com, from what I have gathered, is the URL you want to use. This site should have the SSL setup on it, not sharepoint2. If users are going to use sharepoint2.xyz.com securely, that'll need the SSL as well, but I think that's not the case. If it is, then you need a unique IP per site running SSL, so you'll need 2 IPs for both sites.

I think you want the following

Web App default http://sharepoint2.xyz.com
AAM internet https://sharepoint.xyz.com
AAM extranet http://sharepoint.xyz.com

Again, if you want https://sharepoint2.xyz.com will need it's own IP in IIS.

Check out this blog post, might help clarify it a little http://sp365.co.uk/2011/12/friendly-vanity-urls-and-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for replying!  Correct - http://sharepoint.xyz.com (or https) is the URL that our users use and it works (ideally no one should be using sharepoint2.xyz.com - that was the temp setup to allow us to move content over from 2007).  The problem is that the new site collection at http://sharepoint.xyz.com/sites/NewSite doesn't work at https://sharepoint2.xyz.com/sites/NewSite.  Perhaps IIS isn't the place I should be looking?  Sorry - for not explaining it clearly.  Reading your blog post now.  Thanks!!

Comment: thinking through it some more, does this site collection reference anything using the other URL? Custom masterpage including assets? Check the ULS logs for an error?

Comment: You're answer was the solution.  We hadn't setup a secure AAM.  I find it odd that one site collection worked via https but the other didn't the way it was configured but I'm ok with that now that it works.  Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! IIS will handle the request so that port 443 (SSL) will go to the website setup for it, and if the host header is setup on the same site, not necessarily the same port, it may trick SharePoint into thinking it's setup correctly. Always best to set it up correctly ;)